# How to set the association of two field in db using hibernate

Tags: hibernate, associations

Suppose the table have two fields:

```
url(varchar), type(smallint).
```

When the content of **url** is type of page,the **type** should be **1**,then it should be **0**.
That's to say,

when url like that :

```
/xxx.html
/xx/xx.action
/xxx.jsp
/xxx.htm
.....
```

The **type** should be **1**.

When the url like this:

```
/xx.js
/xx.css
/xx.ico
/xx.jpg
/xx.png
....
```

**type** should be **0**.  It means that this url is not a web page.

And I am using hibernate,I wonder how to mapping this association in the mapping.xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hibernate won't do that for you. This is business logic and should be coded in a service class, or in the entity itself :

```
public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
    if (url.endsWith(".html")) {
        this.type = 1;
    }
    else if (url.endsWith(".gif")) {
        this.type = 0;
    }
    // ...
}
```